# leaflet and xy coordinates

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox

I have list of xy coordinates (shapex, shapey) belonging to UK region. I need to draw a marker with respect to those xy coordinates.

Is it possible to achieve this? if yes then how?

//update.
I have an XY coordinates like (535055.00,164129.00),(535055.00,164129.00),(535408.00,164064.00)
but L.Marker() method need LatLong as an argument. so my problem consist of two queries.

1. Can we convert XY coordinates into LatLong?
2. If no then how can we draw marker at location XY coordinate.

Comment: Yes. But you must tell us what you actually have problems with. Did you already look at leaflet's [Quick Start Guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) and other Tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Just create a variable that stores your coordinates, like this:

```
var coordinates = [[x, y], [x, y], [x, y]]
```

Then loop through your coordinates, and create a marker for each set.

```
for (i = 0; i < coordinate.length; i++) {
   var marker = L.marker(coordinate[i]).addTo(map)
}
```

Comment: I believe LatLong is valid argument for L.Marker() method. I've xy coordinates like (535055.00,164129.00),(535055.00,164129.00),(535408.00,164064.00). I am not sure which format it is but sure its not LatLong format.

Comment: Then you have to determine the format of your coordinates first.

Comment: @Scai: I am completely clueless regarding format. If you can figure out for me looking at numbers then that will be very helpfull. All I know is these coordinates belongs to UK region.

Comment: Here's a link with CRS's used in the UK, maybe you can figure out which CRS your coordinates are. http://www.fieldenmaps.info/cconv/cconv_gb.html

Comment: @Alexandru: I converted one XY coordinate using above link but when  created marker using converted result, I found some strange result. Marker is getting created out side UK-London (those XY coordinates belongs to London city). Or may be I am not able to figure out how to use that tool.

Comment: Using your first set of coordinates (535055.00,164129.00) with Great Britan National Grid Full Co-ordinates, I get WGS coordinates from London